# "ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error" VS designer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, designer, windows-forms-designer, ora-12560

I'm trying to view/edit a Form through Visual Studio Designer and am getting a the following error:

```
   ORA-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
```

How do I set up my form to display within the designer or development machine show intelligent error messages.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a variety of things.  I'm assuming that you can already connect to your database from your development machine?  If not, how about starting with that.  Make sure your TNSNAMES.ora is setup properly and that you're calling the correct service in the same way the database is defined.  Are you using OleDB to make the connection to Oracle?  Maybe an update with more information like your connect string and tnsnames entry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm able to connect through the application and PLSQL.  Oracle is configured correctly on my development machine with the TSNames.ora file.  My problem is isolated to the IDE, specifically the designer.

Comment: Only other things I can think of is possibly an architecture mismatch on the drivers installed (64bit vs 32bit), there's a local driver in the project mismatching with the installation version, or the IDE is running in an environment where it can't see the TNS_ADMIN or ORA_HOME or whatever the environment variables is called.

Comment: I think that may be the cause since I'm running a 64bit workstation with 32bit software... out of my control. thanks